# Neo4j: loop over a map resulting from apoc.load.json in Cypher

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

I want to create a Neo4j graph from data read from a json file, but I am not able to loop over the data I get as a result.

I tried to proceed as in this example:
https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-load-json-from-url/

However, the structure of my apoc.load.json result does not seem to be analogous. I am trying to figure out what I can use instead of:

```
UNWIND data.items as q
```

from the example, as for me, this isn't working.

To understand the structure of my output, I performed this from the Neo4j Browser:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('mytest.json') YIELD value
RETURN keys(value)
```

with the result:

```
["favorites", "sentiment", "content-length", "keywords", "published-at", "reach", "title", "facts", "posts", "normalized-flesch-score", "ext-url", "shares", "last-modified", "score", "xscore", "companies", "quote", "provider", "content-type", "created-at", "categories", "id", "lang", "value", "keyphrases", "annotation", "duplicates", "karma", "topics", "subjects", "al", "possibly-sensitive", "inserted-at", "tags", "replies", "entities", "meta", "domain", "flesch-score", "locations", "parent-id", "relations", "adult", "non-media-entities", "user", "tr", "status"]
["favorites", "sentiment", "content-length", "keywords", "published-at", "reach", "title", "facts", "posts", "normalized-flesch-score", "ext-url", "shares", "last-modified", "score", "xscore", "companies", "quote", "provider", "content-type", "created-at", "categories", "id", "lang", "value", "keyphrases", "annotation", "duplicates", "karma", "topics", "subjects", "al", "possibly-sensitive", "inserted-at", "tags", "replies", "entities", "meta", "domain", "flesch-score", "locations", "parent-id", "relations", "adult", "non-media-entities", "user", "tr", "status"]
...
```

However, when I try to loop over the objects in my output and return one key like this:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('mytest.json') YIELD value
UNWIND value AS v
RETURN v.favorites
```

I get an error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type mismatch: expected List<T> but was Map (line 2, column 8 (offset: 62))

     "UNWIND value AS v"
             ^
```

On the other hand if I loop over for instance value.title rather than value, I get sensible values.

I then looked at examples of looping over a map with cypher, but the maps showed there all had a different structure and the solutions were not applicable (at least to my beginners eye) to my problem.

It would be great if someone could give me some inputs regarding how to loop over the object I have. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `unwind` here.
You can simply return favorites as:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('mytest.json') YIELD value
RETURN value.favorites
```

Comment: To clarify, the results of `Call ... YIELD value` is functionally equivalent to the lines `WITH {json} as map UNWIND map.items`, in the linked blog (It converts a JSON input to a set of rows). So you can just follow the rest of the steps like normal from there.

Comment: Thanks for clarification ☺️

Comment: Dear Raj, many thanks for your answer, but it seems my question wasn't clear enough. Let me be more specific regarding my need. I do not need to access only value.favorites. I'd rather want to be able to access the entire value record, such that I can then access also value.title, value.sentiment etc (i.e. all the features) and set them all as properties of a node. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want. You can access all other properties in the same way.  Do you want to create the node from each of these these values?

Answer (score 0):

Every `value` returned by `apoc.load.json` is a [map](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/maps/), not a list.

To get the value of any property (say, `foo`) from a map, simply use `value.foo` (or `value['foo']`). For example:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('mytest.json') YIELD value
RETURN value.foo
```